# cv::Exception at memory location while looping over cv::Mat object

Tags: c++, opencv

I create an empty matrix `hide_image` with zero values.
Dimentions are right - 672x896. Each element should be filled with value, I do it in loop. But on `(0, 299)` element code throw an exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFD3C063C58 in stego.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000D2B033E5F0. occurred
```

I debugged the function and found out that exceptions depend of j value in loop. I can set j<299 and program will work without problems, but I need all matrix. In command line I see this message:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((unsigned)(i1 * DataType<_Tp>::channels) < 
(unsigned)(size.p[1] * channels())) in cv::Mat::at, file c:\opencv-
3.3.1\opencv\build\include\opencv2\core\mat.inl.hpp, line 1095
```

May be it happens because of wrong matrix initialisation, but why there's shown right dimentions? Rows are right number and if I set j<298, loop ends on i=671. But columns are less and it seems that number 299 does not depend on anything.

```
cv::Mat hide_image;
int hide_image_cols = 0, hide_image_rows = 0;
int i_current = 0, j_current = 15;
int curr_bit = 0;

get_img_dim(image, hide_image_cols, hide_image_rows);

hide_image = cv::Mat(hide_image_rows, hide_image_cols, CV_8U);
hide_image = cv::Mat::zeros(hide_image_rows, hide_image_cols, CV_8U);
std::cout << (hide_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(671, 299)) << std::endl; // exception

for (int i = 0; i < hide_image.rows; i++)
for (int j = 0; j < hide_image.cols; j++) {
//exception when j>298
std::cout << (hide_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)) << std::endl;
}
```

Why this exception occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the matrix data-type and the way you are accessing the elements.

When initializing the `Mat`, if number of channels is not specified, OpenCV assumes single channel by default. It means that if you have specified data-type `CV_8U`, then `hide_image` will be of type `CV_8UC1`.

In the loop, matrix elements are being accessed using data-type `cv::Vec3b` which assumes that the matrix is of type `CV_8UC3`. So in your case, you are iterating over the matrix by jumping 3 bytes at a time instead of the intended 1 byte.

In this scenario, the number `299` does in-fact play an important role in crashing the code. The number of columns in the matrix is equal to **896**. The code should work up-to index 298 because **298 * 3 = 894** and index 894 corresponds to a valid memory address for `hide_image`. When `j` is 299, the loop will try to access **299 * 3 = 897** which will result in out-of-bound memory access.

So the solution for this scenario will be to make sure the data types of initialization and element access are same. So either of the following should work.

Create the input matrix with 3 channels.

```
hide_image = cv::Mat::zeros(hide_image_rows, hide_image_cols, CV_8UC3);
```

## OR

Access the elements with correct data-type for single channel matrix like  this:

```
std::cout << (hide_image.at<unsigned char>(i, j)) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using different types to initialize and loop through the matrix...

During initialization you use `CV_8U` which is an 8 bit pixel representation (one channel).

```
hide_image = cv::Mat(hide_image_rows, hide_image_cols, CV_8U);
hide_image = cv::Mat::zeros(hide_image_rows, hide_image_cols, CV_8U);
```

Then you use `Vec3b` which is a 24 bit per pixel (equivalent to `CV_8UC3`). So it will condume the data 3 times faster, and then you are out of data and a segmentation error is bound to happen.

```
for (int i = 0; i < hide_image.rows; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < hide_image.cols; j++) {
  //exception when j>298
  std::cout << (hide_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)) << std::endl;
  }
```

What can you do:

Initialize with `CV_8UC3` instead of `CV_8U` or use `uchar` instead of `Vec3b`.

BTW,  this line

```
hide_image = cv::Mat(hide_image_rows, hide_image_cols, CV_8U);
```

is unnecessary if you do the next line

```
hide_image = cv::Mat::zeros(hide_image_rows, hide_image_cols, CV_8U);
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct answer is not complete,even if the data types of initialization and element access are same still you will face this issue if you are using the following code

```
std::cout << (hide_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)) << std::endl;
```

but instead we will have to use following code

```
std::cout << (hide_image.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i)) << std::endl;
```

so correct way of accessing values for Mat is `mat.at<data type>(column,row)` not `mat.at<data type>(row,column)`

Comment: That is not correct. Please read the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#ac40425b84f60b39fd35e03814122661f). The access pattern is `(row, column)`.